# Charge SOL Fee Before Minting NFT

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rust, anchor-lang, mint

I want user to pay some fixed SOL fee per NFT before minting. Any code snippet or reference will be helpful. I am using the following NFT minting code.

```
    pub fn mint_nft(
        ctx: Context<MintNFT>,
        creator_key: Pubkey,
        uri: String,
        title: String,
    ) -> Result<()> {

        // minting 
   
        msg!("Initializing Mint NFT");
        let cpi_accounts = MintTo {
            mint: ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
            to: ctx.accounts.token_account.to_account_info(),
            authority: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
        };
        msg!("CPI Accounts Assigned");
        let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info();
        msg!("CPI Program Assigned");
        let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts);
        msg!("CPI Context Assigned");
        token::mint_to(cpi_ctx, 1)?;
        msg!("Token Minted !!!");
        let account_info = vec![
            ctx.accounts.metadata.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.mint_authority.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
        ];
        msg!("Account Info Assigned");
        let creator = vec![
            mpl_token_metadata::state::Creator {
                address: creator_key,
                verified: false,
                share: 100,
            },
            mpl_token_metadata::state::Creator {
                address: ctx.accounts.mint_authority.key(),
                verified: false,
                share: 0,
            },
        ];
        msg!("Creator Assigned");
        let symbol = std::string::ToString::to_string("symb");
        invoke(
            &create_metadata_accounts_v2(
                ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.key(),
                ctx.accounts.metadata.key(),
                ctx.accounts.mint.key(),
                ctx.accounts.mint_authority.key(),
                ctx.accounts.payer.key(),
                ctx.accounts.payer.key(),
                title,
                symbol,
                uri,
                Some(creator),
                1,
                true,
                false,
                None,
                None,
            ),
            account_info.as_slice(),
        )?;
        msg!("Metadata Account Created !!!");
        let master_edition_infos = vec![
            ctx.accounts.master_edition.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.mint.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.mint_authority.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.metadata.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
        ];
        msg!("Master Edition Account Infos Assigned");
        invoke(
            &create_master_edition_v3(
                ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.key(),
                ctx.accounts.master_edition.key(),
                ctx.accounts.mint.key(),
                ctx.accounts.payer.key(),
                ctx.accounts.mint_authority.key(),
                ctx.accounts.metadata.key(),
                ctx.accounts.payer.key(),
                Some(0),
            ),
            master_edition_infos.as_slice(),
        )?;
        msg!("Master Edition Nft Minted !!!");

        Ok(())
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me. First called the Transfer function from `system_instruction::transfer()` and then invoke it using `invoke()`.
What I was doing wrong was that I was calling Transfer function from `Token` instead of `system_instruction`.

```
        let sol_transfer = system_instruction::transfer(
            &ctx.accounts.wallet.key(),
            &ctx.accounts.token_account.key(),
            minting_price * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
            );
    
           invoke(
            &sol_transfer,
            &[
                ctx.accounts.wallet.to_account_info(),
                ctx.accounts.token_account.to_account_info(),
            ],
            )?;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instructions are atomic, so if you have a transfer CPI in the same instruction, and it fails, it will also fail to mint the NFT. It doesn't matter if it comes before or after in the source code.

Example transfer CPI (in anchor). Note that you must take the SystemProgram as an account as well, and the user must sign this tx:

```
    let cpi_accounts = Transfer {
        from: ctx.accounts.some_user_token_acc.to_account_info(),
        to: ctx.accounts.token_destination.to_account_info(),
        authority: ctx.accounts.user_authority.to_account_info(),
    };
    let cpi_token_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.clone();
    let cpi_ctx =
        CpiContext::new_with_signer(cpi_token_program.to_account_info(), cpi_accounts, signer);
    let amount: u64 = 5000;
    token::transfer(cpi_ctx, amount)?;
```